# Saving NSMutableArray in NSUserDefault gives nil

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have already tried this

To set :

> NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
>               [userDefaults setObject:mutArr  forKey:@"userInfo"];
>               [userDefaults synchronize];

To get :

> NSMutableArray *retrieveArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>       retrieveArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"userInfo"] mutableCopy];

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure while saving the array mutArr not an empty array?

Comment: Yes I checked, it was empty. But now its giving me crash at [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mutArr
 forKey:@"Key"];

Comment: i'm asking while saving data in NSUserDefaults is that array having the data or empty aaray?

Comment: then it will give proper data may be some where else userdefaults data updated by empty array once check it.

Comment: Its giving me crash with log : Attempt to set a non-property-list object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55826/discussion-between-sunny-and-user3153627).

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

For Set :

```
NSMutableArray *arrCategoryListSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:object1, object2, nil];   
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrCategoryListSet forKey:@"CategoryList"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

For Get:

```
NSMutableArray *arrCategoryListGet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CategoryList"]];
```

OR

```
NSMutableArray *arrCategoryListGet = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CategoryList"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Save Array

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:youArray forKey:@"Key"];
```

Retrive Array

```
 NSArray *retArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Array"];
```